# Map DB property to a different object property on mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mapping, nestjs

I'm using MongoDB and NestJS.

My DB object has these fields:

```
example1: 'aaaa',
example2: 'bbbb'
```

My server object has these fields:

```
obj1,
obj2
```

I want to map the object like that:

```
example1 -> obj1,
example2 -> obj2
```

I couldn't find anywhere an option to define the column name for the property. Meaning the object on the server must have the exact same properties names as the DB document.
Any idea if there's an option for defining the property name on DB to be mapped to?